# Is unit testing a burden?

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns

I haven't done much unit testing (never TDD'd), but I'm working on a project that I'd like at least the business layer to be unit-testable and there's a couple things I just can't seem to understand.

Say I have a feature that:

- Prompts user for an Excel workbook filename
- Loads the contents of the workbook into a grid
- Displays that grid to the user on a form, which also takes a couple inputs from user
- Displays a modal form with a progress bar that updates while the feature asynchronously...

  - Performs such or such operation (based on user inputs on the now closed form) and - roughly said, ends up importing the grid content into a database table.

I *think* I managed to properly separate business, data and presentation concerns here: the form contains only presentation-related code, data operations are method calls made on the DAL (Linq to SQL) and everything is coordinated in the business logic layer. Dependencies are injected in constructors; for example the form wants a `DataTable`, not an Excel workbook filename.

If I think of tests I could (or *should*) write, I ...simply can't think of any, other than trivial (useless?) ones that validate that a `Foreach` loop does the expected number of iterations, that a `GetMilimeterDimensions` function really does convert inches to milimeters (like, test that `GetMilimeterDimensions(new SizeF(1f,1f))` does return a `SizeF { Width = 25.4, Height = 25.4 }`. Well reading this now it seems like the function's name should rather be something like *ConvertInchToMilimeter* and, well, this feels like a function that belongs as a static method to some *BusinessMath* class. Bad example I guess.

Point is, all these functions and methods I'd want to test, are all `private` and ultimately called by the class' COM-visible `Execute()` method. Does that mean I must make them `public` *just for testing*? Or, what, embed the *behavior* of my functionality into some *FunctionalityImplementation* class that does expose its methods, and have my functionality call these methods instead? Feels like overkill...

Then there's the DAL calls; I'd need to implement some repository pattern in order to mock CRUD operations and be able to write tests that validate whether the expected number of records get inserted... but that's beyond the business layer testability I guess.

Nevertheless, **seems like a lot of work just to get a bunch of green dots in some VS plugin**. I realize that once the test is written, code changes that break a test make you thankful the test was written in the first place, but I think I'm completely missing the point of unit testing and that tests I would write would be meaningless if at all useful; please help me out here, the more I think about it the more it seems to me unit tests are just additional work that imposes its design patterns.

Don't get me wrong (with the question's title I guess), I do see the benefits of TDD, I've read  ASP.NET MVC books written by unit test enthusiasts, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to apply these principles to a simple functionality, let alone to a whole COM-visible library project...

Comment: You might get more responses at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Juhana Ah! That's why writing this post on SO felt somewhat awkward!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit testing isn't a burden; it saves a lot of time, prevents errors, and facilitates refactoring that keeps code maintainable and malleable.

But you might not need unit tests for this project.

The most urgent unit tests would ensure that your business logic does what you think it does. That's really useful where the business logic is complicated, has lots of moving parts, and is likely to grow more complex over time:

```
 Person *p = ...sample person....;
 LoanRequest loan(p, $1,000,000);
 Assert(loan.CanBeApproved(bankPolicy,region,market,term),true);
```

But it's not essential if the underlying logic is simple and evidently correct

```
 Price=Total+Shipping;
```

Similarly, if you're writing a quick widget for immediate short-term use, long-term maintenance isn't your first concern and the role of tests as documentation for future collaborators is probably irrelevant. If you're building a product, though, you'll want those tests.

---

In general, unit tests should primarily be concerned with public behavior. But occasionally you may find it much easier to verify intermediate results that are normally private.  Making a method public, or providing a special hook for testing, can be a reasonable price to pay for confidence that the software does what you think, and will continue to do what you think even after other people start changing it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning some projects may not *need* unit tests, and for addressing the public vs private concern. And for a great answer to a not-so-great question. The project in question is quite a large one, with 2 to 4 programmers involved, and VERY subject to change over time.